# Enable Dynamic TextBox with Dynamic checkbox checked event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding 2 controls Checkbox1 and Textbox1 dynamically. Textbox1 has been disabled by default. I want to enable Textbox1 if checkbox1 is checked. Thanks in Advance.

Praveen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code with both controls, should be something like:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        TextBox1.Enabled = true;
    else
        TextBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Or just `TextBox1.Enabled = TextBox1.Enabled;`

Comment: Thanks For you quick reply. I have been using the above code but because of update panel that i am using on my page. I was unable to achieve that. But anyways i figured it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

in the check event that you want to enable textbox2 just use
    `textbox1.enabled = true;`